# I am trying to copy text froma .txt file to a jtextarea but i get a null pointer exception

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextarea

Everytime I try to read from a `.txt` file I get a `NullPointerException`. I have looked up everything but can not find an answer no matter what.
Would be really nice if anyone can tell me what I did wrong.

```
   public class fileClassOpen implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int dialog = chooser2.showOpenDialog(Other.this);
        if(dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                FileReader fw = new FileReader(path);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fw);
                while(br.readLine() != null) {
                    txtArea.setText(br.readLine());
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the error stack trace?

Comment: What is the relation of **chooser** to **chooser2** other than .... whoops! You would want to append to the textarea as well.

Comment: `catch (IOException e1) {
            }`  never silently swallow exceptions

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
.. FileReader fw = new FileReader(path);` should better be `..
FileReader fw = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile());`. The chooser already provides a `File`. Don't muck about with converting it to a `String` path. 3) Once the code establishes a reader, just [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) 4) ..

Comment: .. 4) And as mentioned by @ScaryWombat, **never** just catch and ignore exceptions. At the very least, call `e1.printStackTrace();`

Comment: To read a file into a `JTextArea` just use the `read(...)` method of the JTextArea. There is no need for your to write the own loop. The method will read the entire file for you.

Comment: .. 5) Almost forgot. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling br.readline() two times. Therefore, you end up reading two lines at a time. Maybe, this is why its throwing NullPointerException assuming everything else works.
I would do something like this:

```
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   txtArea.setText(line);
}
```

Also, Never try to swallow the exception without a proper catch statement.

Comment: At last the text area contents the last line of txt file. Use `append()` to add whole txt file to the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `txtArea.append( br.readLine() );` instead `txtArea.setText(br.readLine())` as `textArea.append(str)` appends the given text to the end of the document. Does nothing if the give string is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys Sorry For Wasting Your Time I Just Realized I Was Accessing The Wrong Variable. Thanks For  The Support! :)